# Gnome shell extension parameters location

Tags: location, user-input, gnome-shell-extensions

More of a user question, I wanted to know where are stored Gnome Shell Extension parameters, I mean user-specific parameters for each extensions ?

To be more specific, here's an example: I installed Media Player Indicator on my former system and I took the time to come up with a nice Pango Markup script to display my music the way I wanted.
I have a complete backup of my system on a hard drive and now I want to reuse this script in my new gnome shell.
I copy-pasted the ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/mediaplayer@patapon.info folder to get the extension, but no parameters were kept, I believe those are not stored there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gnome Shell extensions are only restricted to the [Gnome API](http://devdocs.baznga.org/), which means they could store settings in [files](https://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/GFile.html), [GSettings](https://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/GSettings.html) or using any other API. There is no special storage place for extension settings, although there are conventions like `~/.config/<name>` or `~/.local/share/<name>` for files and `/org/gnome/shell/extensions/<name>` for GSettings.

You'll have to investigate each extension you have or request the extension developer include a backup feature.